# In Vuetify v-text-field is there a way toggle character insert mode?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, overwrite

I have a Vuejs field to allow edit of a duration as HH:MM - currently using Vuetify `v-text-field` [[ref]](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#api-props).

I am successfully using [v-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask) to control input, but it seems the `v-text-field` always inserts values rather than allowing just overwrite.

So attempting to change the hour value from `01:20` to `02:20` actually results in `02:12` as characters are pushed right, which isn't what I'm after.

Is there any way to force character overwrite only in a `v-text-field`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. I did not find a way with `v-text-field`

I ended up using a raw `input` field with an `@input` event handler - and manage the `input.value` directly.

If anyone comes up with a pure `v-text-field` way of doing this, then happy to remove this answer.

[CodeSandBox Link to Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-booth-wvvg4?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)